# ssh: Could not resolve hostname foo: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: networking, ssh, dns

There are three Ubuntu machines (20.04, 21.04) that are accessible from my workstation via their hostnames `foo`, `bar`, `baz`.

However, after a power outage that affects only the network router (Unifi Dream Machine), all 3 systems can no longer be reached by their hostnames

```
~$ ssh x@foo
ssh: Could not resolve hostname foo: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Restarting machines `bar` and `baz` allowed them to be accessible via their hostnames again.

**Question:** Is there something we can do to machine `foo` without restarting it so that we can access the system by its hostname `foo`?

**DHCP Settings:**

[image]

Comment: @guiverc Updated the tags. Added a screenshot from my router DHCP settings page, not sure if this tells us what DNS is being used?